# ASP.NET Out of bound exception accessing a row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this asp.net control:

```
<div class="field" style="text-align: center;">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTags" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false"
        OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDelete">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="tagId" HeaderText="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Common, tlblTags %>" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And I bind my datasource like this from a collection retrieved from database:

```
this.gvTags.DataSource = product.Tags;
this.gvTags.DataBind();
```

In the `OnRowDataBound` I create a popup to show up when the delete button is clicked, so the code is this:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string item = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;

        foreach (Button button in e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            if (button.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                button.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Do you want to delete " + item + "?')){ return false; };";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine, I can see the three rows in my browser and all works as expected (the popup is showing with the correct information etc). But the problem is when I accept the popup so the `OnRowDelete` event is fired.

I want to remove a Tag from the database with a specific `tagId`, so I need to get the position 0 at the current row, so this is my code to do that:

```
protected void OnRowDelete(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
    GridViewRow row = this.gvTags.Rows[index];
    long tagId = Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[0].Text);

    /* Remove the tag */
    productService.RemoveTag(productId, tagId);

    /* Delete the row from gridview */
    this.gvTags.DeleteRow(index);
}
```

The error I'am getting is in this line: `GridViewRow row = this.gvTags.Rows[index];`. I'm getting `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` but I don't understand why. The `index` variable takes a valid int value like 0, 1...

Any ideas on what I'am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you rebind the grid on Delete??

Comment: Hi @User2012384 the error is coming before that línea when I remove the row, so that cannot be the error